# Twitter card / Open graph / Apple touch icon / every page?

Tags: html, ios, facebook, twitter

I have a doubt about this, my head tag in the index page covers the open graph data, twitter card and links for several sizes of apple touch icon. My question is: Is it necessary having these tags within every page of my site? Index page is which loads by default, therefore, I guess that only this page should have it but I have tested that some websites have these calls in every page.

So, what's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it on every page. When someone shares a link on a social network or bookmarks a sub-page of your website the browser or social network will want to use that icon. It is not going to load your home page, so the links to the appropriate icons should be in the head of the page itself.

Comment: Some days later I found a similar solution, therefore I decided to carry it out. Thank so much.

Comment: No problem! For my sites, I usually only bother explicitly setting the apple touch icon. The favicon is found automatically if it is named correctly and placed in the site root and I have found that Facebook is pretty good at picking an appropriate image from the website content without having to set an open graph image.